# How to build an image from a dockerfile using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have the following script, How to I create an image from the Dockerfile archive that is inside the cloned repo?

I've trying Jenkins

```
   "pipeline"{
   "agent any
triggers"{
      "pollSCM(""* * * * *"")"
   }"stages"{
      "stage(""Checkout"")"{
         "steps"{
            "git url":"https://github.com/example.git",
            "branch":"main"
         }
      }"stage(""Building image"")"{
         "steps"{
           //build the image that is inside the cloned repo
         }
      }
   }"post"{
      "always"{
         "mail to":"example@gmail.com",
         "subject":"Completed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
         "body":"Your build completed, please check: ${env.BUILD_URL}"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have docker (or podman) installed on your agent and run `docker build` in the same folder where your `Dockerfile` is.

For more options and examples read the [docker command reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Docker Pipeline plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/).
Assuming you have Dockerfile in your repo root:

```
stage('Build and push docker image') {
  steps {
    script {
      def dockerImage = docker.build(dockerImageName)
      
      docker.withRegistry("http://${params.DOCKER_REGISTRY}", 'registry-credentials') {
        dockerImage.push()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure what "Dockerfile archive" exactly is. If you need to unzip something, there is [Pipeline Utility Steps plugin - unzip](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps).